# Solving the system $ab=9-12i$, $ac=-16-12i$, $db=36$, $dc=-48i$ for complex $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$

Tags: complex-numbers, systems-of-equations

I need to find four Unknown Variables, $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, and I have four equations:

$$\begin{align}
ab &= \phantom{-1}9-12i \tag1\\
ac &=-16-12i \tag2\\
db &=\phantom{-}36  \tag3\\
dc &=-48i \tag4
\end{align}$$

It's look like there are infinite solutions but I didn't succeed to prove it formally.

Comment: Is $i$ here the imaginary unit?

Comment: *"I didn't succeed to prove it formally"* ... You should include what you tried in the question. Someone may be able to help you find your error or suggest ways forward. It'll also help people avoid wasting time (theirs or yours) duplicating your effort or explaining things you already understand.

Comment: Re the comment of Blue, in particular, express $A,C,D$ each in terms of $B$.  Then try to prove that any value of $B$ will satisfy the constraints.

Comment: @AndrewChin Yeah

Comment: @Blue All I try is in a loop, everytime I getting a weird solution

Comment: @Xavi: That sounds interesting ... Show us! :)

Comment: @Blue https://ibb.co/0yXDdWL

Comment: The problem is that there is no $ad$ or $bc$. We would ideally be able to find $abcd$ and then divide by $abc$ etc. to find the individual variables. All we know is that that $ad \cdot bc = abcd = -576-72i$.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha [confirms](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+p%2Cq%2Cr%2Cs+pq%3D9-12i%2C+pr%3D-16-12i%2C+qs%3D36%2C+rs%3D-48i) there are infinitely many solutions.

Comment: @TobyMak Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a formal proof. The first and second equation yield
\begin{align*}
b & = -\frac{1}{a}(12i - 9),\\
c & = -\frac{1}{a}(12i + 16).
\end{align*}
Then the third equation gives
$$
a=\frac{d(3-4i)}{12}.
$$
Then the forth equation is automatically satisfied. So over $\Bbb C$ we have infinitely many solutions, parametrized by all nonzero $d$ in $\Bbb C$, given by
$$
(a,b,c,d)=\left(\frac{d(3-4i)}{12},\frac{36}{d},-\frac{48i}{d},d\right)
$$

Note that there are only finitely many solutions with $a,b,c,d\in \Bbb Z$, where the expressions $x+yi$ are elements in the ring $\Bbb Z[i]$.